# How to format a few-shot prompt for GPT4 Chat Completion API?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, completion, gpt-4, few-shot-learning

**I'm trying to use the GPT4's chat completion API for the following prompt:**

```
For each situation, describe the intent. Examples:


Situation 1: Devin gets the newspaper.

The intent of Situation 1: Devin intends to read the newspaper.

Situation 2: Jamie works all night.

The intent of Situation 2: Jamie intends to meet a deadline.

Situation 3: Sydney destroys Ryan.

The intent of Situation 3: Sydney intends to punish Ryan.

Situation 4: Lindsay clears her mind.

The intent of Situation 4: Lindsay intends to be ready for a new task.

Situation 5: Rowan wants to start a business.

The intent of Situation 5: Rowan intends to be self sufficient.

Situation 6: Lee ensures Ali’s safety.

The intent of Situation 6: Lee intends to be helpful.

Situation 7: Riley buys lottery tickets.

The intent of Situation 7: Riley intends to become rich.

Situation 8: Alex makes Chris wait.

The intent of Situation 8: Alex intends
```

As you can see, I want to complete the sentence that says "Alex intends". This prompt is intuitive for GPT3's Completion API where you only had to put one prompt that has all the few-shots examples.

**However, I don't know what is the best practice to perform the same prompting with GPT4's ChatCompletion API.** I've checked out https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/blob/main/examples/How_to_format_inputs_to_ChatGPT_models.ipynb
where they provided an example of how to do few-shot prompting, but my prompt is not "conversational" as you can see.

**I'm not even sure whether the "name" parameter impacts the result's quality. Does anybody have an answer to this?**

What I thought of so far is to format my prompt like this as the content from the above link instructed:

```
messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "For each situation, describe the intent. Examples:"},
        {"role": "system", "name":"Situation 1", "content": "Devin gets the newspaper."},
        {"role": "system", "name": "The intent of Situation 1", "content": "Devin intends to read the newspaper."},
        {"role": "system", "name":"Situation 2", "content": "Jamie works all night."},
        {"role": "system", "name": "The intent of Situation 2", "content": "Jamie intends to meet a deadline."},

...
        {"role": "system", "name":"Situation 8", "content": "Alex makes Chris wait."},
        {"role": "user", "name": "The intent of Situation 8", "content": ""},
    ]
```

**Is this a proper way to do few-show with GPT4 ChatCompletion API? Please let me know if you have a better solution or explanations on why certain parts of my prompt needs work.**

So far, I've simply put the original prompt into one user content, just like it is GPT3's Completion API:

```
messages=[
    {"role": "user", "content": "For each situation, describe the intent. Examples:


Situation 1: Devin gets the newspaper.

The intent of Situation 1: Devin intends to read the newspaper.

Situation 2: Jamie works all night.

The intent of Situation 2: Jamie intends to meet a deadline.

Situation 3: Sydney destroys Ryan.

The intent of Situation 3: Sydney intends to punish Ryan.

Situation 4: Lindsay clears her mind.

The intent of Situation 4: Lindsay intends to be ready for a new task.

Situation 5: Rowan wants to start a business.

The intent of Situation 5: Rowan intends to be self sufficient.

Situation 6: Lee ensures Ali’s safety.

The intent of Situation 6: Lee intends to be helpful.

Situation 7: Riley buys lottery tickets.

The intent of Situation 7: Riley intends to become rich.

Situation 8: Alex makes Chris wait.

The intent of Situation 8: Alex intends"}
]
```

It does work, but I was wondering if I can boost the API's performance if I follow a certain practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out our [GPT best practices guide](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt-best-practices) which talks about how to do prompting effectively. The reality is that prompt engineering for tasks like this is much more art than science today. I suggest trying both approaches but my hunch is the one with each example as a user message / assistant response separately will perform better based on experiments I have seen.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the ChatCompletions API, but I know how few shots are generally done for the GPT-4 and GPT4-32K Apis.

You were actually pretty close to the few shot best practices in your try.

Template for best practices for few shots as far as I know:

```
messages=[

{"role":"system","content":"The_Prompt_You_Want_To_Give"},

#Few Shot starts here:

{"role":"user","content":"First_Example_Data_That_We_Send_To_GPT"},
{"role":"assistant","content":"First_Example_Answer_We_Expect"},

{"role":"user","content":"Second_Example_Data_That_We_Send_To_GPT"},
{"role":"assistant","content":"Second_Example_Answer_We_Expect"},

{"role":"user","content":"Third_Example_Data_That_We_Send_To_GPT"},
{"role":"assistant","content":"Third_Example_Answer_We_Expect"},

{"role":"user","content":"Fourth_Example_Data_That_We_Send_To_GPT"},
{"role":"assistant","content":"Fourth_Example_Answer_We_Expect"},
.....


#Finally send the data for which we want GPT to run the prompt and find solution

{"role":"user","content":"Content_We_Want_GPT_To_Process_Based_On_Prompt"}

]
```

So the above is the template for Few-Shot using openAI.

The part that u missed in your try is the **role** of **assistant**.

So the solution would be

```
messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "For each situation, describe the intent. Examples:"},
        {"role": "user", "content": "Devin gets the newspaper."},
        {"role": "assistant", "content": "Devin intends to read the newspaper."},
        {"role": "user",  "content": "Jamie works all night."},
        {"role": "assistant",  "content": "Jamie intends to meet a deadline."},

...
        {"role": "user", "content": "Alex makes Chris wait."},
         ]
```

I am not quite sure of the "name" parameter you have used, thats a new one for me so I have removed it. If you are sure about the name parameter keep it also in the body(messages).

Thanks